# Notepad++ insert into specific part of matched strings

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a tab separated text file with phone numbers opened in Notepad++. Some numbers have the format:

*+36-six additional number-*

I would like to change them to:

*+3636-six additional number-*

*\+36\d{6}\t* matches these numbers in the middle of the lines

*\+36\d{6}$* matches these numbers at the end of the lines

What should I replace them with to do that?

Comment: `\+36` to `+3636` ?

Comment: @splash58 I need the restriction to have six additional numbers after 36 other way it changes in unwanted numbers too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to match

```
\+36(\d{6})
```

And replace it with

```
\+3636\1
```

Where `\1` refers to the first `(capturing group)` of the matching pattern, that is the 6 digits.

If you need to make sure you replace only the numbers in the middle of the lines and end of the lines, use `\+36(\d{6})(\t|$)` and replace with `\+3636\1\2` to preserve the tabulations.